# Finding a signal in noisy data

Tags: noise, detection

I have a large data set that was collected by a 5 GHz oscilloscope, so I basically have an array of voltages with each index being a very small time step apart.  I am looking for a specific signal in this data set that would only be present for a very small time frame and so most of the data will not contain this signal.  The issue is that the signal I am looking for has an amplitude less than or equal to that of the background noise.  The signal should also be a fairly wideband.

My question starts then with how to find this signal?  My first thoughts are there must be something I can do to take advantage of the fact that my noise and signal probably follow different distributions, but I am not sure.

I know this is a fairly open-ended question so I am just looking for suggestions into general methodologies that help uncover a signal that is not consistent with background noise, but of the same or lesser amplitude.

Comment: Do you know exactly what the signal will look like?

Comment: not exactly sure, but it should occur over a relatively brief period of time compared to the sampled data time frame and should be decaying in frequency

Comment: How will you know you've found the signal if you aren't sure what it looks like? (e.g. Why wouldn't a random answer be good enough?)

Comment: I know the exact moment in time when the signal should appear, and I know it should be decaying in frequency.  That is all I have to go on though.

Comment: Ah, so you know when it happens, and from the sampled data at that point you want to figure out what it looks like.  Is that right?

Comment: Perhaps you could try resampling the data at a decreasing sampling rate, then FFT and look for peaks. This works only if you know the frequency curve, like whether it's exponential, linear, etc. As for the noise, something that analyzes with an orthogonal basis should be sufficient if your SNR isn't terrible. Do know what sort of SNR to expect?